# How to let custom post type posts show in standard post archive (like in homepage)?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, archives

If I, for example, create a custom post type named 'tutorial', how do I get it to also show up in places like "Recent posts" , etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooking the following function with the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter will add one or more CPTs to the regular archive pages:

```
function wpse94041_cpts_in_archives( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() ) { // more conditional tags possible, if applicable
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
            'post',
            'tutorial' // add as many CPTs to this array as you like
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse94041_cpts_in_archives' );
```

Your theme's *functions.php* file would be a good fit for the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I put the script at the end of my theme's functions.php but sadly it didn't work. Would there be something more to configure?

Comment: Worked after removin the  if( is_category() || is_tag() ) conditional. Not sure if it is ok to skip that.

Comment: If you remove the conditional, this will modify *every* query. Rather than removing it, I'd recommend modifying it to your needs. Use some other [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) instead, that are more suiting to your situation.

Comment: Weirdly I found out that it only works as long as 'page' is in the array. Otherwise no document found would be returned.